# What does the word 「こい」mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

I'm not sure if it is an adjective meaning strong, a noun meaning intention or neither.

Here is the sentence I came across.

> 僕なんとしても選手になりたかったので申しこむと沼田さんが腕ずくで**こい**というから...

Additional context:

The story started when people found Numata, who was unconscious, and the speaker was there with him. The speaker then told them:

> けんかじゃありません
>
> 寮対抗の予選試合をやったんです
>
> 僕なんとしても選手になりたかったので申しこむと沼田さんが腕ずくでこいというから...
>
> グローブではめて段平先生に教えられたとおりにしたら..こうなっちゃったんです

It surprised the others because the speaker was a novice at boxing, and Numata is the one who was supposed to represent the dormitory in a boxing competition but lost to him.

Comment: What happens afterwards? I'm thinking the imperative form of 来る might make sense.

Comment: `なりたかったんので` <-- It's なりたかったんで or なりたかったので, no?

Comment: Ya, given the context, it's probably 来【こ】い, the imperative form of 来【く】る, as @user3856370 notes.

Comment: There's not enough context and the sentence has an unnatural typo, so I would suggest taking a screencap of the page in question. But if I had to venture a guess based on the given information, I would hypothesize that Numata is a sports coach, essentially telling the speaker that "If you want to play in competitions, you have to prove your worth". In this case 来い would indeed be the correct meaning as noted previously.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo. The consequence is that the person who said this sentence unexpectedly knocked out Numata unconscious.

Comment: @George; Was this on purpose? Was Numata really telling him to fight him (presumably in the context of a martial arts manga?), or do we end up figuring out that it was actually a misunderstanding by the person who said the sentence?

Comment: @VVayfarer Yes, it came from a boxing manga. Actually, Numata is another competitor who fought with the speaker and lost in a qualifying round of a competition.

Comment: @George: What is the context of the line itself? Who is the speaker talking to, is he responding to some other person and does the other party respond? Also, if you have the original line said by Numata (assuming he said anything) that would clarify this too.

Comment: @VVayfarer The story started with people found Numata lie unconsciously and speaker still being there with him. The speaker said to the people with these lines

けんかじゃありません　寮対抗の予選試合をやったんです　僕なんとしても選手になりたかったので申しこむと沼田さんが腕ずくでこいというから...　グローブではめて段平先生に教えられたとおりにしたら..こうなっちゃったんです






It made other people surprising because the speaker just started training boxing and Numata is the one that should be a boxer representative for the dormitory but lost to him.

Answer (score 1):

Here, it means「（腕{うで}ずくで）来{こ}い」, or "come (by force)".

Given the context (an informal boxing match to determine the representative boxer of the dormitory), it can literally mean "Come at me", in the sense of "Show me what you've got.". A different translation with the same underlying meaning would be "(If you want to participate in boxing competitions,) then prove your strength." It could also mean something like

> 「腕{うで}ずくでリングに上{あ}がって来{こ}い」

which could literally mean "get inside the ring" or more figuratively something along the lines of "rise to the same stage / same level", i.e. something along the lines of

> 「試合{しあい}に出{だ}させてもらえるよう、腕前{うでまえ}を証明{しょうめい}しろ」
>
> "Prove your skill, if you want to participate in competitions."